# I need to remove single inverted commas from list

Tags: python

When I open [contestant file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNK3G.png), I'm getting below output and below list is having single *inverted comma* in all indexes, because of that I'm facing issue.

**output**

```
:
[['1951', '1874'], ['1957', '1519'], ['1962', '1985'], ['1967', '2369'], ['1971', '2784'], ['1977', '2439']]
```

I need the list like below. please let me know, what i need to do?

```
year = [1951,1957,1962,1967,1971,1977]
contest = [1874,1519,1985,2369,2784,2439]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you haven't tried anything yet, you would be better off trying to find a tutorial.

Comment: What is an "inverted coma" ?

Comment: The quotes are displayed because the objects in the list are strings (class `str`) - that's how python displays strings.  maybe they should be objects of a different class?

Comment: [int(i) for i in data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why two loops , you can do in one loop :

```
data=[['1951', '1874'], ['1957', '1519'], ['1962', '1985'], ['1967', '2369'], ['1971', '2784'], ['1977', '2439']]

year=[]
contenst=[]

for i in data:
    year.append(int(i[0]))
    contenst.append(int(i[1]))

print(year)
print(contenst)
```

output:

```
[1951, 1957, 1962, 1967, 1971, 1977]
[1874, 1519, 1985, 2369, 2784, 2439]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) your lists together into tuples of `str`:

```
>>> l = [['1951', '1874'], ['1957', '1519'], ['1962', '1985'], ['1967', '2369'], ['1971', '2784'], ['1977', '2439']]
>>> year, contest = zip(*l)
>>> year
('1951', '1957', '1962', '1967', '1971', '1977')
>>> contest
('1874', '1519', '1985', '2369', '2784', '2439')
```

Then you can [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map) them to `int`:

```
>>> list(map(int, year))
[1951, 1957, 1962, 1967, 1971, 1977]
>>> list(map(int, contest))
[1874, 1519, 1985, 2369, 2784, 2439]
```

**Note:** Since `map()` returns a generator, you need to wrap `list()` to convert it to a list. The other option is to use a list comprehension: `[int(x) for x in lst]`.

Answer (score 2):

For the first list:

```
year=[int(i[0]) for i in [['1951', '1874'], ['1957', '1519'], ['1962', '1985'], ['1967', '2369'], ['1971', '2784'], ['1977', '2439']]]
```

For the second list

```
contest=[int(i[1]) for i in [['1951', '1874'], ['1957', '1519'], ['1962', '1985'], ['1967', '2369'], ['1971', '2784'], ['1977', '2439']]]
```

Comment: i think `int(i[1])` you can use because OP asked to remove the quotes also .

Answer (score 2):

```
data =[['1951', '1874'], ['1957', '1519'], ['1962', '1985'], ['1967', '2369'], ['1971', '2784'], ['1977', '2439']]
year=[int(x[0])  for x in data]#=>[1951, 1957, 1962, 1967, 1971, 1977]
contest=[int(x[1])  for x in data]#=>[1874, 1519, 1985, 2369, 2784, 2439]
```

Comment: converting to int will remove quotes